# Proxy Tunneling Through SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, proxy

We have an HTTP proxy available on our facility's intranet. The proxy is accessed through a local IP address (192.168.x.x) and cannot be accessed from outside.

I can connect to a head node on the intranet through SSH, which has a public IP address. I can expose any port I'd like on this node.

Is there a way to somehow forward the traffic from an exposed port on the head node to this local proxy and back out to the world? I've been looking up this problem, but most solutions can only relay the traffic via SSH Port Forwarding to a local port on the device with SSH access, not another device with a different IP address.

Answer (score 0):

You can try from a machine on the Internet :

```
ssh -L 3128:proxyIp:proxyPort user@headNode
```

Then on that machine, you can use localhost:3128 as proxy.

Try on a machine inside intranet first to make sure there is not security implications.